# icCube parent/child sort view id = parent_id

Tags: iccube

I have a child/parent view where the child and parent are both strings. When I try to deploy the cube I get the following error:

Parent/Child View 'AreaSort' without a single root member, at least one root member is mandatory. A Root member is defined with PARENT_ID = NULL or PARENT_ID = ID.

However, I do have PARENT_ID = ID for the root member. If instead I set PARENT_ID = NULL then everything deploys properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an [issue](http://issues.iccube.com/issue/ic3pub-265) with the sorting view that does not support this case (parentId = id ). It's fixed and will be part of the following icCube version ( next to 6.0.3 ).